# addListener for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to print a google map, after the map is fully loaded.

[..]

```
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.de/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var gh;


function initialize() {
    //alert("Starte Funktion");
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    gh = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -7.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:15,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         center: gh
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

}

function calcRoute() {
    //alert("Starte calcRoute");
    //alert("<?php echo $adresse; ?>");
    var start = "Recklinghausen Akkoallee 45";
    var end = "Recklinghausen <?php echo $adresse; ?>";
    var request = {
        origin:start, 
       destination:end,
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
       avoidHighways: true,
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'idle', function(){
        alert('Funktion wird aufgerufen!');
        //window.print();
    });
}
</script>
```

[..]

```
<body onload="initialize();calcRoute();">
```

But the addListener fires the information when the map is started and not fully loaded?

Comment: This is the best I could do: [the Map object supposedly fires a `tilesloaded` event](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map), but when I changed your `addListenerOnce` to "tilesloaded" instead of "idle", I still got the alert box before the images showed up. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a setTimeout function to delay the print call.

```
directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            setTimeout(function() { alert('Funktion wird aufgerufen!'); }, 2000);
        }
    });
```